# Aligning two dom side by side in safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I have a two dom, I need to align it side by side.

```
<div class="two">Two</div>
<div class="one">One</div>
```

Output : One Two

That is class="one" dom value need to display 1st then class="two" value. I need to do it without re-arranging the dom. can anyone give me a solution for safari browser.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below styling to achieve your requirement.

```
.two
{
  display:inline-block;
}
.one{
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

It should work in all browsers.

Comment: Yes that is working. Also I should center align the both text, how it is possible?

Comment: You can use **text-align** property
`text-align:center;`

Comment: both text I need to center align, Because of float left property ".one" class not aligning center

Comment: did you try `text-align:center`

Comment: This might be with the Safari, try using `text-align:-webkit-center;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137936/discussion-between-jijo-cleetus-and-mahi).

Comment: That also I tried, Because of the float left property it stays always at left, only ".two" class centering.

Comment: did you try by applying specific width to both div say `width:200px` and check the text alignment